# SAPUI5 Property binding, Variable as path

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I want to dynamically set the binding path of smartfields:

```
var form = new sap.ui.comp.smartform.SmartForm({
    title: "not important"
});

form.bindElement("/param"); // 

for (i = 0; i <obj.length; i++){
var elem = new sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField({
    value: "{obj[i]getAttribute("name")}" 
});
```

`obj[i]getAttribute("name") = name and /param/name = "Aline"`

I want the value "Aline" to be display in the field.

Any idea is welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like below which is using the [bindProperty](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindProperty) method of ManagedObject (which SmartField inherits from) ...

```
var elem = new sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField().bindProperty("value",obj[i]getAttribute("name"));
```